# Angular JS field valid only its value greater tan zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I got the following text box in my form, its value changing dynamically when user change a category ( select box ). Initially, it was set to 0.

```
$scope.validCats = "0";
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="validCats" value=""  type="text" class="form-control input-text phone_number" required >
```

User can't change its value directly. I need to show a validation error ( ie. the field is invalid ) if the value is zero or less. simple its valid only if the value is greater than zero

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `type` to `number` and add following:

```
<input ng-model="validCats" type="number" min="1"
    class="form-control input-text phone_number" required >
<span ng-show="validCats === 0 || validCats === '0'">Invalid categories</span>
```

And

```
$scope.validCats = 0 // instead of "0"
```

And you should also set a CSS so that Chrome & Firefox does not the spinner for that textfield when `type="number"`

```
.input-text {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
.input-text::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none
    margin: 0
}
.input-text::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none
    margin: 0
}
```

You should add `min="1"` validator (HTML5 only) in the input field so prevent submission and you can also add a check in the method like this:

```
// called from ng-submit
$scope.onFormSubmit = function() {
    // just additional check
    if ($scope.validCats === 0 || $scope.validCats === "0") {
        return false;
    }

    // do other thing after form submission
}
```

Comment: but still the form will get submit coz of non-empty number field